# Slow response from Django Rest Framework with annotated queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and simply trying to filter out objects which have more than 0 related items but as soon as I add in a filter to my annotation that includes a datetime, the response time goes from milliseconds to 90 seconds or so.

Here is the code that takes ages:-

```
class EventVenueViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = EventVenue.objects.prefetch_related("eventblock_set__eventslot_set__event").annotate(
            num_slots=models.Count(
                "eventblock__eventslot",
                filter=Q(eventblock__eventslot__event=None) & Q(
                    eventblock__eventslot__start_time__gt=timezone.now()
                    + timedelta(days=2)
                )
            )
        ).filter(num_slots__gt=0)
```

If I remove the filter that includes the DateTimeField (start_time)...

```
class EventVenueViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = EventVenue.objects.prefetch_related("eventblock_set__eventslot_set__event").annotate(
            num_slots=models.Count(
                "eventblock__eventslot",
                filter=Q(eventblock__eventslot__event=None)
            )
        ).filter(num_slots__gt=0)
```

it is very fast.

But the presence of that datetime filter slows it down to the point of being useless.

It's nothing to do with db lookups - it's doing 8 of those so that's fine.

The SQL query looks fine and the results are correct - it's just taking soooooo long!

Any ideas?

EDIT

After a bit more investigation, it turns out that it's the prefetch_related("eventblock_set__eventslot_set__event") that's causing the problem!

If I remove that, then it works perfectly well, even with the start_time filter in there.

The trouble is, I do need the prefetch_related because I want to return the related objects in the serialized data.

So now I'm even more confused!

Comment: It's probably because of the spanning relationship in that filter not merely the DateTimeField. Have you tried inspecting the queries with Django Debug Toolbar?

Comment: Try adding `.prefetch_related('eventblock__eventslot')` before `.annotate`. This way it will get all eventslot entries at once as separate SELECT and will not get it from db one by one

Comment: I've edited the example code to make it clearer that it really is the DateTimeField and it's not related to the db lookups as I'm already doing the prefetch_related - I just omitted it before to make the code look easier to read but I can assure you, it's there.

Comment: It turns out that the problem is being caused by the prefetch_related call! See my edit for details

Answer (score 0):

You should you proper debug tools (like silk) if you're chasing performance gains.

From your queryset, i guess you have four models, EventSlot, EventBlock, EventVenue and Event. EventSlot has FKs to Event and EventBlock while EventBlock has a FK to EventVenue.
If thats the case, you might see a performance increase from the following.

```py
class EventVenueViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    qs = EventVenue.objects.all()
    qs = qs.annotate(
        num_slots=models.Count(
            "eventblock__eventslot",
            filter=Q(eventblock__eventslot__event=None)
        )
    )
    qs = qs.filter(num_slots__gt=0)
        
    slot_qs = EventSlot.objects.select_related("event")
    block_qs = EventBlock.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch("eventslot_set", queryest=slot_qs)
    )
    qs = qs.prefetch_related(Prefetch("eventblock_set", queryset=block_qs))
```

This will remove one query and one prefetch mapping.

If you don't serialize `num_slots` and you only use it for filtering, you should consider using `.alias()` instead of `.annotate()` since it will remove it from the select